# Google Sheets sorting by time

Tags: google-sheets

So I am in charge of office hours for a class at my University. I have to send out a google form every week for the students to sign up. The way the form is sent back, the data is grouped by Name, and the times they are available are grouped by days.

To make it easier on myself, I want to group it by times. Basically, I want it so that each day/time will have its own row, and the names of the people who want the time slot would be grouped together in the adjacent column.

I already separated the groups of times so that each time has its own cell, but I cannot figure out how to regroup the data by time.

I should also mention that each session of OH is 30 minutes and that each student can only receive one session of office hours a week because of limited availability. I also need to group the sessions into blocks so that the teachers won't have idle time (basically a teacher will have office hours from 5:00-6:30 PM on Tuesday, instead of 5:00-5:30 PM and 6:00-6:30 PM on Tuesday and 8:00-8:30 PM on Thursday). Grouping the names of the people who want office hours by the times that they are available would make it a lot easier to set up that week's office hours schedule.

Here's a link to an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fRYYNUoEcgynU9cDMoXzsyjtIir4hsRlfFYJau36a78/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: post "data" (snippet) and "desired output"

Comment: @pnuts I was tired and figured that the solution would be the same.

Comment: @user3616725 what do you mean? I'm sorry I am new to this

Comment: @pnuts does my edit clarify things?

Comment: How many students are there? I have an idea,  but its not really feasible if there are hundreds of students...

Comment: +1 using GAS. A solution using native functions would be possible, but enormously convoluted.

Comment: @pnuts thanks for telling me about shortened URLs. I didn't think it would be a problem. Also, I have no idea how to use GAS (I have extremely little programming experience). I could try to learn, but would rather keep everything in Google Sheets.

Comment: @user3616725 not that many. At max there are about 40-50, and a lot of them don't sign up for office hours

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have a look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HIUkOdXJK_hReA-ZuCoFx6NotWY2xuYAqP13qmjM3Uo/edit?usp=sharing) ( i have only turned on sharing temporarily, co copy this to your own drive)

Look at the "matrix choices" sheet.
I created a Matrix of students and times (which I think is better), but there is also a list of names for each timeslot on the end too.

have a play changing some of the 1's (sessions applied for) to "G" (short for Granted). Ive set up some conditional formatting and data validation.